# Log API responses with status codes 400+ (fails) in Fabric

Tags: android, retrofit, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to log all my API responses with status code 400+ in Fabric as non-fatal exception. Simplified method for obtain created `RestAdapter` look's like this:

```
public static Api get() {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new RestAdapter
                .Builder()
                .setEndpoint(API_URL)
                .setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
                    @Override 
                    public Throwable handleError(RetrofitError cause) {
                        Crashlytics.logException(new ApiException(cause.getMessage() + ": " + cause.getUrl(), cause));
                        return cause;
                    }
                })
                .build()
                .create(Api.class);

    }
    return mInstance;
}
```

The problem is, all of this exceptions are collapsed to one in Fabric, because the same exception is thrown everytime at same line of code. I want to classify them accoring to status code of response.

[image: Collapsed exceptions]

I'm thinking how to solve this problem and few ideas come to my mind:

- Generate exeptions (for example `ApiException404` etc.) at runtime.
- Throw exceptions in different lines (enormous switch with handling all of the status codes)

... but both of the approaches are really unsightly. Thanks for every advice or idea.